# Stop the Auto replacement

Tags: htc-one

Hi I have an HTC One a9 I want too keep the word prediction but I don't want the auto replacement I used to do that with Samsung but with HTC I can't find the solution for this problem . Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

For me, you go Settings > Language & Input > [Button below "Current keyboard" that has your keyboard name] > Text correction > Set "Auto-correction" to off.